# queue basic functions (put) calling (the program crashes)

Tags: c++, data-structures, memory-management, queue

So I wrote some basic operations to learn queues.The problem is that when I run the program it crushes and I don't know why.
The code:
header

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

typedef int Atom;
struct Element {
    Atom info;
    Element* succ;
};

struct Queue {
    Element *head, *tail;
};

Queue InitQ(void);
bool IsEmpty(Queue q);
void Put(Queue& q, Atom x);
Atom Get(Queue& q);
void PrintQ(Queue q);

#endif
```

functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

Queue InitQ(void)
{
    Queue q;
    q.head = q.tail = 0;
    return q;
}

bool IsEmpty(Queue q)
{
    if (q.head == NULL && q.tail == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void Put(Queue& q, Atom x)
{
    Element *p = new Element;

    if (q.head == nullptr)
    {
        q.head = q.tail = p;
    }
    else
    {
        q.tail = q.tail->succ = p;
    }
}

Atom Get(Queue& q)
{
    Element* p = q.head;
    int aux;
    aux = p->info;
    q.head = p->succ;
    if (q.head == nullptr) q.tail = nullptr;
    delete(p);
    return aux;
}

void PrintQ(Queue q)
{
    if (IsEmpty(q))
    {
        cout << "Empty queue";
    }
    else
    {
        Element* p = q.head;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            cout << p->info << " ";
            p = p->succ;
        }

    }
}
```

main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Queue q=InitQ();
    Put(q,2);
    Put(q, 3);
    Put(q, 7);
    PrintQ(q);
    Get(q);
    PrintQ(q);
    return 0;
}
```

When I call Put function the program it crushes.I think I don't call it in good way.Can you explain how to call it ?

edit: I edited the code, now the program shows me some big numbers then it crushes.What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is `q.tail` pointing to when you do `q.tail->succ = p` ? (hint: `tail` is not initialized). You need to add a first element before you can set its succesor

Comment: btw you call `InitQ()` in `main` but ignore its returned value. Did you mean to write `Queue q = InitQ();` instead? (this alone wont fix the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `IsEmpty` should be declared like

```
bool IsEmpty( const Queue &q )
{
    return q.head == nullptr;
}
```

The function `Put` is invalid. The pointer head is not set when the queue is empty. The function can be defined the following way

```
void Put( Queue& q, Atom x)
{
    Element *p = new Element { x, nullptr };

    if ( q.head == nullptr )
    {
        q.head = q.tail = p;
    }
    else
    {
        q.tail = q.tail->succ = p;
    }
}
```

The function Get should be defined at least like

```
Atom Get(Queue& q)
{
    Element* p = q.head;
    int aux;
    aux = p->info;
    q.head = p->succ;
    if ( q.head == nullptr ) q.tail = nullptr;
    delete(p);
    return aux;
}
```

And at last in main you have to write

```
Queue q = InitQ();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!I edited the code now I want to display the queue.I wrote a PrintQ function to print the queue but when I run the program it shows me some big numbers then it crushes.Where's the mistake?

Comment: @DaniVaja You should not change the original question adding new question after it was already answered. I can not reproduce the problem. You even did not copy and paste the functions I showed. In the function Put you did not initialize the new node. Please try to copy and paste the functions I showed as is.

Comment: Thank you, it;s working but I don't know what {x, nullptr} is doing

Comment: @DaniVaja It initializes the created object.

Comment: Thank you for your help!